# How to use groupby, select, count(*) and where commands of SQL together in Pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am new to writing SQL queries in python.

I have an SQL query like this.

```
 select Category, Date, count(*) as Uniq, sum(FCnt) as Total,
 sum(FCnt)/count(*) as RepRatio, Mod,Act,Exp, Sel,
 Bias,Sel_B,Bias_B,Bias_P,Con_Num, Sel_Str,CG_D,CGM,TC,P_Value from
 FCntt_Table where Sel_B=Bias_B group by
 Mod,Act,Exp,Bias_P,Con_Num,CG_D order by RepRatio desc, Uniq desc;
```

I am trying to convert this query into a python code so that i can perform the operation done by this query using python. I came across options using Pandas.

I have the SQL table as .csv format.

The code I have written is

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

tips=pd.read_csv("fc.csv")


tips["Total"]=tips.groupby(['Mod','Act','Exp','Bias_P','Con_Num','CG_D'])["FCnt"].transform("sum")

tips[tips['Sel_B'] == tips['Bias_B']]
print tips.groupby(['Mod','Act','Exp','Bias_P','Con_Num','CG_D']).agg({'Uniq':np.size})

print tips.head(5)
```

But this gives me error for Uniq. Kindly help me with this code.

**Sample Data:**(Provided by OP in comments)

```
Date,Category,FCnt,TC,Mod,Con_Num,SC,Sel_P,Bias_P,Sel_B,Bias_B,Act,Exp,CG_D,CGM,P_val
20200622,T1,5,RE,649,SB3,01,0,0,0,1,0,GP2,cg1,0,Pattern1
20200622,T1,1,RE,649,SB3,10,1,0,0,1,0,GP2,cg2,0,pattern2
20200622,T1,4,RE,649,SB3,11,0,0,0,1,0,GP2,cg1,0,pattern1
20200622,T1,4,RE,649,SB3,11,1,0,0,1,0,GP2,cg1,0,pattern1
```

Comment: You handled `sum(FCnt) as Total` correctly, use a similar approach for `count(*) as Uniq`

Comment: Like how a single SQL query can do this..Can't we do the same thing in a single panda query...I have written "where" of SQL separately, calculating Total separately....Please don't take me wrong..  I'm just curious to know if this is possible

Comment: count(*) of SQL is similar to size() of pandas...But the thing is i am not able to understand how to write the panda query for deriving the "Uniq"

Comment: @HariPriya You can use `groupby(...).size()` directly.

Comment: @shaikmoeed I tried tips["Uniq"]=tips.groupby(['Mod','Act','Exp','Bias_P','Con_Num','CG_D']).size() This gives incompatible index of inserted column with frame index - type error

Comment: the thing is data is pretty huge..as there are 19 parameters

Comment: @HariPriya Please check the updated answer. Let me know if it solved your problem or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to take the sum and count of the group, I have used aggregation function in different way i.e., `.agg({'FCnt':(np.sum, np.size)})`.

**Code:**

```
tips=pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
# filtered_tips = tips[tips['Sel_B'] == tips['Bias_B']] # In given sample data, there is zero records after filter.

# So, considering original df
tips.groupby(['Mod','Act','Exp','Bias_P','Con_Num','CG_D']).agg({'FCnt':(np.sum,np.size)})
tips.columns = ['Total', 'Count']
```

---

**Output:**

```
print(group_df.reset_index())

   Mod  Act  Exp  Bias_P Con_Num CG_D  Total  Count
0  649    0  GP2       0     SB3  cg1     13      3
1  649    0  GP2       0     SB3  cg2      1      1
```

Comment: It gave me  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 694, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12231)
KeyError: 'FCnt' error..Thanks for the reply...

Comment: @HariPriya Check the name `FCnt` is present or not in `filtered_tips.columns`.

Comment: The Column FCnt is not generated...in the line filtered_tips.groupby(['Mod','Act','Exp','Bias_P','Con_Num','CG_D']).agg({'FCnt':np.sum,'Uniq':np.size}) i get the Key error

Comment: @HariPriya What is the output of `filtered_tips.columns`?

Comment: Index([u'Date', u'Category', u'FCnt', u'TC',
       u'Mod', u'Con_Num', u'SC', u'Sel_P', u'Bias_P',
       u'Sel_B', u'Bias_B', u'Act',
       u'Exp', u'CG_D', u'CGM', u'P_val'],
      dtype='object')
This is the output